# Problems with parsing xml with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xpath, simplexml

I need to parse xml file and retrieve some information. But 
Simple_XML_string function returning not all content of xml.

Here the following xml.

```
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="URL">
    <id>
   URL(UserId='',UserType='')
    </id>
    <title type="text">RecommendationScenarios(UserId='',UserType='')</title>
    <updated>2017-02-10T05:08:15Z</updated>
    <category term="PROD_RECO_RUNTIME_SRV.RecommendationScenario" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <link href="RecommendationScenarios(UserId='',UserType='')" rel="self" title="RecommendationScenario"/>
    <link href="RecommendationScenarios(UserId='',UserType='')/Scenarios" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Scenarios" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Scenarios">
    <m:inline/>
    </link>
    <link href="RecommendationScenarios(UserId='',UserType='')/ContextParams" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContextParams" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ContextParams">
    <m:inline/>
    </link>
    <link href="RecommendationScenarios(UserId='',UserType='')/ResultObjects" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ResultObjects" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ResultObjects">
    <m:inline>
    <feed xml:base="URL">
    <id>
    URL(UserId='',UserType='')/ResultObjects
    </id>
    <title type="text">ResultObject</title>
    <updated>2017-02-10T05:08:15Z</updated>
    <author>
    <name/>
    </author>
    <link href="RecommendationScenarios(UserId='',UserType='')/ResultObjects" rel="self" title="ResultObject"/>
    <entry>
    <id>
    URL(ScenarioId='SAP_TOP_SELLER_HOME_PAGE',ResultObjectType='SAP_HYBRIS_PRODUCT',ResultObjectId='37511')
    </id>
    <title type="text">
    ResultObject(ScenarioId='SAP_TOP_SELLER_HOME_PAGE',ResultObjectType='SAP_HYBRIS_PRODUCT',ResultObjectId='37511')
    </title>
    <updated>2017-02-10T05:08:15Z</updated>
    <category term="PROD_RECO_RUNTIME_SRV.ResultObject" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <link href="ResultObject(ScenarioId='SAP_TOP_SELLER_HOME_PAGE',ResultObjectType='SAP_HYBRIS_PRODUCT',ResultObjectId='37511')" rel="self" title="ResultObject"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
    <d:ScenarioId>SAP_TOP_SELLER_HOME_PAGE</d:ScenarioId>
    <d:ResultObjectType>SAP_HYBRIS_PRODUCT</d:ResultObjectType>
    <d:ResultObjectId>37511</d:ResultObjectId>
    <d:ResultObjectScore>1.00000</d:ResultObjectScore>
    </m:properties>
    </content>
    </entry>

    </feed>
    </m:inline>
    </link>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
    <d:UserId/>
    <d:UserType/>
    </m:properties>
    </content>
    </entry>
```

I need to get information from `content type=application` and i need to retrieve

```
<m:properties>
<d:ScenarioId>SAP_TOP_SELLER_HOME_PAGE</d:ScenarioId>
<d:ResultObjectType>SAP_HYBRIS_PRODUCT</d:ResultObjectType>
<d:ResultObjectId>4934</d:ResultObjectId>
<d:ResultObjectScore>0.49999</d:ResultObjectScore>
</m:properties>
```

I'm trying to parse using php (simple_xml_string function).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem using xpath and `namespaceRegister`.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
  $xml->registerXPathNamespace('m', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata');

  $products = [];
  foreach($xml->xpath('//m:properties') as $key=>$event) {
      $products[] = strval($event->xpath('d:ResultObjectId')[0]);
  };
```